# SQL - How to select top 3 rows for each unique value returned

Tags: sql-server

Having troubles figuring out a query here and need some input. I have a query that is joining multiple tables, and returns multiple rows for each unique value (VIN)

```
SELECT 
   T1.VIN
  ,T1.station                                    
  ,T1.complete_time   
  ,T2.location
  ,T1.previous_status 

FROM DBName.dbo.table_name1 T1 WITH (NOLOCK)

LEFT OUTER JOIN DBName.dbo.table_name2 T2  WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON T2.object_key = T1.queue_key

LEFT OUTER JOIN DBName.dbo.table_name3 T3 WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON T3.op_name = T1.op_name

LEFT OUTER JOIN DBName.dbo.table_name4 T4 WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON T1.VIN = T4.VIN

WHERE T1.VIN IN
(
 'ABC12301'
,'ABC12302'
,'ABC12303'
,'ABC12304'
,'ABC12305'
,'ABC12306'
,'ABC12307'
)

ORDER BY T1.complete_time desc
```

Here is what my output is. It will show all returned rows for each unique VIN

```
VIN      Station  Complete_Time        Location    Previous_Status
ABC12301  SOLD    2017-02-22 09:07:00     Y            800
ABC12301  PIT     2017-02-22 09:05:00     P            610
ABC12301  Drag    2017-02-22 09:03:00     P            610
ABC12301  Rain    2017-02-22 09:03:00     P            610
ABC12301  Trim    2017-02-22 09:01:00     P            610
ABC12302  SOLD    2017-02-22 08:59:00     Y            800
ABC12302  PIT     2017-02-22 08:57:00     P            610
ABC12302  Drag    2017-02-22 08:56:00     P            610
ABC12302  Rain    2017-02-22 08:54:00     P            610
ABC12302  Trim    2017-02-22 08:50:00     P            610
ABC12303  SOLD    2017-02-22 08:49:00     Y            800
ABC12303  PIT     2017-02-22 08:47:00     P            610
ABC12303  Drag    2017-02-22 08:46:00     P            610
ABC12303  Rain    2017-02-22 08:44:00     P            610
ABC12303  Trim    2017-02-22 08:40:00     P            610
.
.
.
.etc.............
```

What I'd like this query to do is only show the first 3 rows for each unique VIN, like the example below

```
VIN      Station  Complete_Time        Location    Previous_Status
ABC12301  SOLD    2017-02-22 09:07:00     Y            800
ABC12301  PIT     2017-02-22 09:05:00     P            610
ABC12301  Drag    2017-02-22 09:03:00     P            610

ABC12302  SOLD    2017-02-22 08:59:00     Y            800
ABC12302  PIT     2017-02-22 08:57:00     P            610
ABC12302  Drag    2017-02-22 08:56:00     P            610

ABC12303  SOLD    2017-02-22 08:49:00     Y            800
ABC12303  PIT     2017-02-22 08:47:00     P            610
ABC12303  Drag    2017-02-22 08:46:00     P            610
```

Comment: Which kind of database? `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: Most likely sql_server... MySQL doesnt support syntax like "WITH (NOLOCK)".. please fix the tags

Comment: SQL Server doesn't like NOLOCK either. It can and will return duplicate and/or missing rows as well as a whole host of other strange things. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 4):

If it is `SQL-Server`, then this might work. Also, since you are doing the left join on T3,T4 without pulling any data from them, are they really necessary? Should they be a `INNER JOIN`s? Lastly, I agree with Sean Lange's opinion above.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
       T1.VIN
      ,T1.station                                    
      ,T1.complete_time   
      ,T2.location
      ,T1.previous_status 
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.VIN ORDER BY T1.complete_time) AS RowNum
    FROM DBName.dbo.table_name1 T1 --WITH (NOLOCK)

    LEFT OUTER JOIN DBName.dbo.table_name2 T2  --WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON T2.object_key = T1.queue_key

    LEFT OUTER JOIN DBName.dbo.table_name3 T3 --WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON T3.op_name = T1.op_name
    -- Is T3 needed?
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DBName.dbo.table_name4 T4 --WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON T1.VIN = T4.VIN
    -- Is T4 needed?
    WHERE T1.VIN IN
    (
     'ABC12301'
    ,'ABC12302'
    ,'ABC12303'
    ,'ABC12304'
    ,'ABC12305'
    ,'ABC12306'
    ,'ABC12307'
    )
)
SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNum < 4;
```